# How to Store or save new line Serial Read and Print as String

Tags: arrays, serialization, arduino, hex, storing-data

I've this code to send Hex to external hardware using serial write (UART Communication) : {0xbb, 0x00, 0x22, 0x00, 0x00, 0x22, 0x7e}
, and then the serial hardware give reply to arduino and I print using Serial.print: BB 02 22 00 11 D0 34 14 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 24 12 14 11 62 77 69 EA 7E
The problem it's actually printed as new line/ the hardware sent hex code one by one
ex : BB
02
22
etc.
It's printed as no line ending because I use Serial.print.
How can I recieve and store all data/hex code from hardware reply until it's complete (until 7E or 0x7e). And then print it as string.
I've tried some buffer code or serial event it doesn't work properly. Thank

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial serial(D5,D6);

//#define DEBUG
unsigned char incomingByte;

void sendIdentifyCmd ()
{
  serial.write (0xbb);   
  serial.write ((byte)0x00);
  serial.write (0x22); 
  serial.write ((byte)0x00);                 
  serial.write ((byte)0x00);                 
  serial.write (0x22);
  serial.write (0x7e);             
#ifdef DEBUG
  Serial.print (0xbb);
  Serial.print (0x00);
  Serial.print (0x22);
  Serial.print (0x00);
  Serial.print (0x00);
  Serial.print (0x22);
  Serial.print (0x7e);
  Serial.println ();
#endif
}

void setup ()
{
  Serial.begin (115200);
  serial.begin (115200);
  Serial.println ("begin initial Serial!\n");
}

void loop ()
{
  sendIdentifyCmd ();
  delay (2);
  while(serial.available () > 0)
  {
      incomingByte=serial.read ();
      if (incomingByte <= 0x0F) Serial.print("0");
      Serial.print (incomingByte,HEX);
      Serial.print (' ');
     
  }
  Serial.println ();
  delay (1000);
}
```

I've tried serial read bytes until like the code below, but it's just print "abc: 2abc: 5"

```
void loop ()
{
  sendIdentifyCmd ();
  delay (2);
  while(serial.available () > 0)
  {
      incomingByte=serial.read ();
     
      if (incomingByte <= 0x0F) Serial.print("0");
      Serial.print (incomingByte,HEX);
      Serial.print (' ');
  }
  Serial.println();
  delay(1000);
  while(serial.available()>0)
  {
    abc=serial.readBytesUntil(0xFF, buffer, 24);
    Serial.print("abc: ");
    Serial.print(abc, HEX);
  }
  Serial.println ();
  delay (1000);
}
```

Comment: return of readBytesUntil is count of bytes read

Comment: Use `Sting incomingString=serial.readString();`  instead `incomingByte=serial.read ();`

Comment: I've tried to use read as string, but it printed random character on serial monitor

Answer (score 0):

If you know length of the external hardware response (typically you should know), you can use `.readBytes()` method to read all the serial buffer safely.

A good practice in serial communication, is to sent your message inside a **timer interrupt** and receive the response in the main loop. see the following snippet:

```cpp
#define BUFF_SIZE 24   // define buffer length
byte Buff[BUFF_SIZE];  // define buffer byte array

byte Message2Send[10]; // some message to send

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    
    SetupTimer1(); // define a function to setup timer1 registers and enable interrupts

}


void loop()
{
    if (Serial.available () > 0)
    {
       Serial.readBytes(Buff, BUFF_SIZE);
    }
}

// Timer1 Interrupt callback 
ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect) 
{
    Serial.write(Message2Send, 10);
}

// Setting timer1 interrupt at 1Hz
void SetupTimer1() 
{
  cli();      //stop interrupts
  
  // Timer Register setups
  TCCR1A = 0;
  TCCR1B = 0;
  TCNT1  = 0;
  // set compare match register for 1Hz increments
  OCR1A = 15624;  // = (16*10^6) / (1*1024) - 1 

  TCCR1B |= (1 << WGM12);
  TCCR1B |= (1 << CS12) | (1 << CS10);  
  TIMSK1 |= (1 << OCIE1A);

  sei();  //allow interrupts
}
```

for more information about timers see [this](https://www.instructables.com/Arduino-Timer-Interrupts/)

Comment: Based on my result print without space : BB 02 22 00 11 D0 34 14 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 24 12 14 11 62 77 69 EA 7E, it's 24 bytes, is it correct?

Comment: Yes of course, the length of your hardware response is 24 bytes.